# Cannot build and install Geary for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, vala

I'm running Elementary OS (Ubuntu) and need to build and install Geary, the mail client.

I have downloaded and extracted it and installed most of the "missing" dependencies. But few still remain.

I am up to the point where, in Terminal, I enter:

`./configure`, which then results in missing dependency errors:

```
cmake version 2.8.7
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Icon cache will be updated
-- Desktop database will be updated
-- Generated desktop file will be checked for errors
-- xgettext found
-- Found Vala: /usr/local/bin/valac 
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.20.1
--   found Vala, version 0.22.1
-- Unity messaging menu support: OFF
-- Unity launcher support: ON
-- Targeting WebKitGTK 1.10.0 to 2.0.4
-- Vala fatal warnings: ON
-- checking for modules 'gthread-2.0;glib-2.0>=2.32.0;gio-2.0>=2.28.0;gtk+-3.0>=3.6.0;gee-0.8>=0.8.5;libnotify>=0.7.5;libcanberra>=0.28;sqlite3>=3.7.4;gmime-2.6>=2.6.0;libsecret-1>=0.11;libxml-2.0>=2.7.8;unity;webkitgtk-3.0>=1.10.0;webkitgtk-3.0<=2.0.4'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0>=3.6.0' not found
--   package 'gee-0.8>=0.8.5' not found
--   package 'libsecret-1>=0.11' not found
--   package 'webkitgtk-3.0>=1.10.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:475 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Reference tracking: OFF
-- GSettings schemas will be compiled.
-- GSettings schemas will be compiled in-place.
-- GSettings schemas will be installed into /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
Creating POT file
-- Found Valadoc: /usr/bin/valadoc 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Unable to prepare build directory.
```

So I'm trying to install each dependency one by one, but failing at the fisrt. The first on is Gtk. I've downloaded and extracted it, then I've followed a tutorial and tried to:

`~/gtk+-3.8.8$ make`
and
`sudo make install`

or `make install`

but, it tells me:

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

So I can't `make` Gtk/can' install required dependency. I've read 8 different site so far from google and they all say the same thing but have no real solution and nothing's worked.

So I'm stuck.

Is there a different, or, more automatic way to install these dependencies? Or do I always have to manually download and configure/make/install them in the terminal? It seems as though this is becoming more and more common with everything I install, there is always a missing dependency and the solutions often require me to install something else which also requires a dependency. Talk about recursion!

How do I install these dependencies that Terminal is asking for?

Comment: Also, I am finding it very difficult to even _find_ a lot of dependencies, so if you could help with that I would really appreciate it!

Comment: A downvote? Are you serious? You could at-least explain why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Ubuntu packaging system (apt) and should be asked on http://www.askubuntu.com 

Answer (score 5):

In general, unless you know what you're doing or really need a specific version of a dependency, you should be using packages from your distribution instead of trying to build and install from tarballs.  Specifically, you need the development packages for gtk+-3.0, gee-0.8, libsecret-1, and webkitgtk-3.0, so:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libsecret-1-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
```

As for why the downvote, not sure why the initial one, but mine was because this doesn't really belong on SO; [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) would be more appropriate.  Furthermore, it's [pretty easy to find the answer](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=package+gtk+-3.0+not+found) to this question, so I doubt you did much research.

Comment: Thanks, the above I've already tried, but forgot to mention because it's just 1 more thing I've tried that hasn't worked at all: `E: Unable to locate package libsecret-1-dev`

Comment: That's curios, because that's the correct package name. Which Ubuntu release is Elementary OS based on? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsecret&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all

Comment: BTW: You can do `apt-cache search libsecret` to find the package names similar to libsecret.